# Can't get resources to work on rails on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

I'm a rails newbie having trouble getting `resources` to work on rails when deployed on Heroku. It works in my development environment (Cloud9), but not on Heroku. My routes.rb is as follows:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  root 'pages#home'
  get '/home', to: 'pages#home'

  resources :characters
end
```

When I run it on Cloud9, it works as it should and `rake routes` returns:

```
        Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                    Controller#Action
          root GET    /                              pages#home
          home GET    /home(.:format)                pages#home
               GET    /home(.:format)                pages#home
    characters GET    /characters(.:format)          characters#index
               POST   /characters(.:format)          characters#create
 new_character GET    /characters/new(.:format)      characters#new
edit_character GET    /characters/:id/edit(.:format) characters#edit
     character GET    /characters/:id(.:format)      characters#show
               PATCH  /characters/:id(.:format)      characters#update
               PUT    /characters/:id(.:format)      characters#update
               DELETE /characters/:id(.:format)      characters#destroy
```

but on Heroku, I get an error message saying `We're sorry, but something went wrong. If you are the application owner check the logs for more information.` and the logs show me this:

```
2018-01-10T21:58:43.431137+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 6ms (ActiveRecord: 4.1ms)
2018-01-10T21:58:43.433165+00:00 app[web.1]:                 FROM pg_attribute a LEFT JOIN pg_attrdef d
2018-01-10T21:58:43.433157+00:00 app[web.1]: ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  relation "characters" does not exist
2018-01-10T21:58:43.433168+00:00 app[web.1]:                WHERE a.attrelid = '"characters"'::regclass
2018-01-10T21:58:43.433154+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2018-01-10T21:58:43.433166+00:00 app[web.1]:                   ON a.attrelid = d.adrelid AND a.attnum = d.adnum
2018-01-10T21:58:43.433159+00:00 app[web.1]:                                           ^
2018-01-10T21:58:43.433174+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2018-01-10T21:58:43.433169+00:00 app[web.1]:                ORDER BY a.attnum
2018-01-10T21:58:43.425295+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by CharactersController#new as HTML
2018-01-10T21:58:43.433172+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/controllers/characters_controller.rb:7:in `new'
2018-01-10T21:58:43.433158+00:00 app[web.1]: LINE 5:                WHERE a.attrelid = '"characters"'::regclass
2018-01-10T21:58:43.433170+00:00 app[web.1]: ):
2018-01-10T21:58:43.422364+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/characters/new" for 24.155.28.170 at 2018-01-10 21:58:43 +0000
2018-01-10T21:58:43.433168+00:00 app[web.1]:                  AND a.attnum > 0 AND NOT a.attisdropped
2018-01-10T21:58:43.433161+00:00 app[web.1]: :               SELECT a.attname, format_type(a.atttypid, a.atttypmod),
2018-01-10T21:58:43.433164+00:00 app[web.1]:                      pg_get_expr(d.adbin, d.adrelid), a.attnotnull, a.atttypid, a.atttypmod
2018-01-10T21:58:43.433173+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2018-01-10T21:58:58.637394+00:00 app[web.1]:                      pg_get_expr(d.adbin, d.adrelid), a.attnotnull, a.atttypid, a.atttypmod
2018-01-10T21:58:58.637395+00:00 app[web.1]:                 FROM pg_attribute a LEFT JOIN pg_attrdef d
2018-01-10T21:58:58.626386+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/characters/new" for 24.155.28.170 at 2018-01-10 21:58:58 +0000
2018-01-10T21:58:58.637397+00:00 app[web.1]:                WHERE a.attrelid = '"characters"'::regclass
2018-01-10T21:58:58.637402+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2018-01-10T21:58:58.637392+00:00 app[web.1]: :               SELECT a.attname, format_type(a.atttypid, a.atttypmod),
2018-01-10T21:58:58.637389+00:00 app[web.1]: LINE 5:                WHERE a.attrelid = '"characters"'::regclass
2018-01-10T21:58:58.637400+00:00 app[web.1]: ):
2018-01-10T21:58:58.637401+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/controllers/characters_controller.rb:7:in `new'
2018-01-10T21:58:58.635689+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 6ms (ActiveRecord: 4.0ms)
2018-01-10T21:58:58.637399+00:00 app[web.1]:                ORDER BY a.attnum
2018-01-10T21:58:58.637385+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2018-01-10T21:58:58.637391+00:00 app[web.1]:                                           ^
2018-01-10T21:58:58.637396+00:00 app[web.1]:                   ON a.attrelid = d.adrelid AND a.attnum = d.adnum
2018-01-10T21:58:58.637398+00:00 app[web.1]:                  AND a.attnum > 0 AND NOT a.attisdropped
2018-01-10T21:58:58.629873+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by CharactersController#new as HTML
2018-01-10T21:58:58.637388+00:00 app[web.1]: ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  relation "characters" does not exist
2018-01-10T21:58:58.637403+00:00 app[web.1]:
```

What's wrong and how do I fix it?

Comment: have you ran your migrations? `heroku run rake db:migrate`

Comment: @Josh Brody Um? actually, don't remember :P let me try that...

Comment: @Josh Brody Thank you! wow... that's embarrassing :)

Comment: @Josh Brody if you answer it, I can mark it as accepted/closed, thanks for the super fast reply!

Comment: :) it happens to everyone!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you haven't done anything absolutely with where you're putting your mdoels, `ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  relation "characters" does not exist` is indicative of not having the table inside of PostgreSQL.

`heroku run rake db:migrate` should do the trick.